# Plotting 3-d function using Evaluate and Table

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation

I want to plot $z(F, x, \lambda)$ where I fix a few values of $F$ and $\lambda$ and see how it varies with $x$. With 2-d functions, I could vary the second parameter easily using a combination of `Evaluate` and `Table`. I'm not able to get it to run for a 3-d function: What's going wrong here?

```
z[F_, x_, \[Lambda]_] := (Exp[\[Lambda] (1 - F)] - 
     1) * (Exp[F*x*\[Lambda]] - 1)/(F*x*\[Lambda]);
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[z[F, x, \[Lambda]], {{\[Lambda], {0.1, 1}}, {F, {0.5}}}]], {x, 
  0, 2}]
```

The error is `Table::write: Tag List in {\[Lambda],{0.1}} is Protected.`

Comment: You have an extra set of `List` brackets. The two iterators in your `Table` should not be enclosed in `List` brackets. Use 

`Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[z[F, x, \[Lambda]], {\[Lambda], {0.1, 1}}, {F, {0.5}}]], {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.75, 0.45}]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
z[F_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, \[Lambda]_?NumericQ] :=
(Exp[\[Lambda] (1 - F)] - 1)*(Exp[F*x*\[Lambda]] - 1)/(F*x*\[Lambda]);

Plot[Evaluate[Table[z[F, x, \[Lambda]], {F, {0.5}},
{\[Lambda], {0.1, 1}}]], {x, 0, 2},AxesLabel -> {x, z},
PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
z[F_, x_, \[Lambda]_] := (Exp[\[Lambda] (1 - F)] - 
     1)*(Exp[F*x*\[Lambda]] - 1)/(F*x*\[Lambda]);
Manipulate[
 Plot[z[F, x, \[Lambda]], {x, 0, 2}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1.5}], {\[Lambda], 0.1, 1}, {F, 0.1, 0.5}]
```

[image]

Have fun!